# d3.js: Initial brush size/graph selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I currently have a basic line graph set up using d3.brush for a viewport. The data I have coming in is from various queries in a postgres db and so is subject to change.

When the page is loaded, the entire dataset spans the graph and the selection below reflects that. Is there a way that I could have the selection in the viewport (and therefore the graph itself) select say, a day or a few hours or so and then the user could span across this or resize the viewport as they see fit?

Because sometimes the data I'm dealing with can be relatively large and it'd ruin a lot of the graph if I was to fit hundreds of points into one small area.

Currently, my "brushed" function looks like so:

```
function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection;
    console.log(x2);
    x.domain(selection.map(x2.invert, x2));
    focus.selectAll(".point")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            var time = timeParser(d.timestamp);
            return x(time);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        });
    focus.selectAll(".trendline")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return line(d);
        });
    focus.selectAll(".area")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return area(d);
        });
    focus.select(".axis.x").call(xAxis);
}
```

Am I right in thinking its x.domain with the selection as a parameter that must be affected here?